# customized javascript confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirmation

[image]I have customized confirmation box....When I press the logout the box is displayed...If cancel is pressed the box is closed the control remains in the same page...When yes is pressed ,logout has to take place....For me,cancel is working fine...But when user presses yes, there is no response....Could anyone help me...Thanks in advance...

My code:

```
<s:a href="logout" cssClass="planTabHeader" id="logoutId"> <img src="../../KY/images/common/header/lock.png" alt="logout" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;" /> &nbsp;Log out</s:a>
```

javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $($('#logoutId')).click(function (event) {


        var msg = "";
        var buttons = {};
        msg = "Are you sure you want to logout?";

        buttons["Yes"] = doLogout;

        buttons["Cancel"] = closeDialog;
        if (msg != "") {

            showDialog(buttons, "cancelConfirm", msg, "dialogNormal",
                "Confirmation", 470);

        }
        return false;
    });
});

function doLogout() {
    document.getElementById("logoutId").href = "logout";
}

function closeDialog() {
    /* alert("action is closeDialog"); */
    $("#cancelConfirm").dialog("close");
    $("#cancelConfirm").dialog("destroy");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$($('#logoutId'))`?  Why not just `$('#logoutId')`?  Why is your `<a>` tag in the `s` namespace?

Comment: What is `showDialog`?

Comment: `document.getElementById("logoutId").href="logout";` just changes the `<a>` tag's `href`.  Do you want to actually go to that page?

Comment: showDialog is the function which I uses to create the confirmation box...s:a is for struts annotation...Actually If yes is clicked...doLogout function will be called...If Cancel is pressed, closeDialog function will be called

Comment: we need to showDialog.

Comment: Your doLogout function is just setting the href attribute of a link, you've already return false from the 'click' function so all it does is update the href attribute and that's it. It doesn't 'do anything' with the link or follow it.

Comment: I need to make changes in doLogout() function such that the link is followed...But I dont know how to do that..

Comment: @miah : problem is not with showDialog...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment above maybe your function should be

```
   function doLogout() {
window.location = "/logout"; // not sure on your url structure
  }
```

Comment: logout is my struts action name